# How to print each item in a list’s score

Tags: python, list

I have a list where I assigned a score for each item in it.
For example,

```
    my_list = [1,2,3]
    fitnesses = []
    score = 0
    score1 = []
    score2 = []
    for x in my_list:
       If x > 1:
       score1 = score + 1
       if x > 2:
       score2 = score1 + 3
    for x in my_list:
          fitnesses.append(score1)
   print(fitnesses)

    I get [4,4,4] as an output
    I want to get [0,1,4]
```

I WANT to print each item’s score that’s in my_list, however for some reason I always get the last item in the list’s score repeated however long the list is. How do I get each item’s individual score?

Comment: What is `&amp;amp;gt;`? This isn't valid Python.

Comment: It’s the greater than symbol. I fixed it so it’s formatted correctly.

Comment: When you do this: `score1 = score + 1`, `score1` is no longer a list, it's an integer. You then append it several times to `fitnesses`.

Comment: beside that not being valid python, you also overwrite your score1 and score2 list variables, perhaps you want to append instead there

Comment: Yes I want it to be an integer, not a list

Comment: So then you're getting what you want. You make `score1` = 4, then append it (`fitnesses.append(score1)`) for every item in `my_list`. That makes your result `[4, 4, 4]`. If you want it to be an integer, why start with `score1 = []`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning up a couple redundant variables as well as adjusting the initialization of `score`, we get the desired output:

```py
my_list = [1,2,3]
fitnesses = []
for x in my_list:
    score = 0
    if x > 1:
        score += 1
    if x > 2:
        score += 3
    fitnesses.append(score)
print(fitnesses)
```